# How can I download ipa file from ipad on El Capitan?

Tags: itunes, ipad, applications, ios

Unfortunately [Stash](http://hedonicsoftware.com/stash.html) got removed from the iOS App Store, but I need to transfer it from my iPad onto my new iPhone. How can I do that? If I'm right first I need to download it and install it with iFunBox. Where does the iTunes store the ipa files when I do a manually backup?

PS: I tried to restore phone from iCloud backup, it tries to download it but it stuck on "Waiting.." status. The most important thing for me is the data in the app. I tried to contact the developer but I got an automatic reply.

Comment: If the developer is still active and only pulled the app, u can still download it. Can you give us the app name

Answer (score 2):

Sync your iPad with iTunes, which will download all not already downloaded Apps to iTunes - and then sync your iPhone with iTunes - that's it.

iTunes store the ipa-files in `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications`